# Why i get invalid syntax in this line ----> f.writelines(f'{attrib} = {VIDEO_CHECK.get(index)}\n')

Tags: python

When i run  my python file that show this error

```
   f.writelines(f'{attrib} = {VIDEO_CHECK.get(index)}\n')
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Because you're trying to use an f-string in a version older than 3.6.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Either upgrade to a newer version of Python, or use the older string formatting functions.

Comment: That is my source code --> https://www.ideone.com/mlxFh8

Comment: Select `Python 3` from the language menu, not `Python`.